# How can i solve a Scanner error when i click on enter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, indexoutofboundsexception

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
mainMenu = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Soo each time i click on enter it "explodes" and says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at tESTedit.main(tESTedit.java:50).
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Are you reading anything before that line?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i only want to repair that error, and no its not reading anything before that.

Comment: @Ricardo Ah, I misread your question. If you just click Enter, an empty `String` will be read in. That means there won’t be any characters to access.

Comment: You can fix it by typing something, or not chaining immediately on a `charAt(0)` when you're getting an empty string

Comment: To make your code safer, always check the length before accessing a hard coded value whether in String or Array

Comment: @Logan exactly now, how can i enter a Enter without giving a error like that ?

Comment: @Ricardo As @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi said, check the length of the `String`.

Comment: @Ricardo: Then that should result in compilation error as you can't directly assign a `char` to `String` as `charAt(0)` method returns a `char` not `String`

Answer (score 2):

Just check the string has content

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
String input = null;

if (scan.hasNextLine() && !(input = scan.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
  char mainMenu = input.charAt(0);
  // do something else
} else {
  System.err.println("Nothing was entered");
}

System.out.println("Hello " + input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never try to access an index from a String or array without checking its length and write a safer code like this,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        char mainMenu = s.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(mainMenu);
    }
}
scan.close();
```